# How to work with PluginResult object in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, plugins

I am trying to work with a Phonegap plugin for which there is little documentation (I already contacted the dev - no response).  I am new to Phonegap and am confused as to how to, in Javascript, interact with what is returned from the plugin which appears to be a PluginResult object.  What is PluginResult object and how do I get data from it in JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the `PluginResult` class [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/PluginResult.java)

The `PluginResult` can be created with one or two params:

The first one (mandatory) is the Status

```
public enum Status {
        NO_RESULT,
        OK,
        CLASS_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION,
        ILLEGAL_ACCESS_EXCEPTION,
        INSTANTIATION_EXCEPTION,
        MALFORMED_URL_EXCEPTION,
        IO_EXCEPTION,
        INVALID_ACTION,
        JSON_EXCEPTION,
        ERROR
    }
```

- `ERROR` will call the error callback on your plugin
- `NO_RESULT` will not call any callback
- `OK` will call the success callback
  not sure about the others

The other param is the item the plugin returns, it can have different types and deppending on the type it has, you have to treat it differently on the javascript part. 
Some examples:

- If the plugin result is `JSONArray` you will get an array on javascript
- If the plugin result is `JSONObject` you will get an object on javascript
- If the plugin result is `String` you will get a string

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!